# How to avoid :make command from closing the buffer from where I called it

Tags: vim, makefile

Say I am working in a file called foo.cpp and I have my makefile in that source directory, I call :make from the vim buffer of foo.cpp. The terminal appears and it prompts me "press enter to continue", I tap enter and now the file I had open in vim is closed and I am at an empty buffer at the source directory. If my file does not get compilation errors it doesn't close the file and gets me back to the file I was working on but I it has compilation errors it closes the file.

Comment: Did you check `:h :make`?

Comment: I didn't understand much but I pressed ctrl-o the same command I use to get from go to definition and it worked to get me back to my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `:h :make`:

> 7. If [!] is not given the first error is jumped to.

So, use `:make!` instead.

Comment: Since I had a linking problem in my c program, perhaps it opened the empty file since it has nowhere to jump to